# Select a range of number and group them in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Numbers in the below format:

```
Number Extension 
123     1
123     24
123     6
123     10
123     11
123     25
123     2
123     3
123     13
```

I need a result set like this:

```
Number Begin End
123     1     3
123     6     6
123     10    13
123     24    25
```

There are several numbers and each number has these extension in random order. I need to group them in the range for each number such that those extensions are existing.

Let me know for any questions/clarifications.

Comment: what happened to `2` in result and how `6` is at both `Begin` and `End`

Comment: 1, 2, 3 are consecutive, so we need to group them as a range. So, we have 1 as being and 3 as end. there is no number before or after 6, so we have 6 as being and 6 as end

Comment: Got it.. Please add this explanation in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting a consecutive number from each extension.  For sequential extensions this will be a constant.  Then, you can group by this difference:

```
select number, min(extension), max(extension)
from (select n.*, (extension - row_number() over (partition by number order by extension)) as grp
      from numbers n
     ) n
group by number, grp
order by number, min(extension);
```